# How to view constraints into Ancestor and Descendant in Xcode 11 storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Storyboard used to show AutoLayout constraints into 2 groups:

- `Sibling & Ancestor Constraints`
- `Descendant Constraints`

However, from Xcode 11, it shows in `Horizontal` and `Vertical` and it hurts my soul.

[image]

Is there any way to see the constraints in the old way (`Sibling & Ancestor Constraints` and `Descendant Constraints`)?

Comment: I think it is stupid change of Xcode 11.

Comment: I think, NO there is no option to change the look as easier version of Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe this change. It makes it impossible to work with complex designs. The only solution I can find is to return to Xcode10 when it is necessary to work with the storyboards. So use Xcode11 and Xcode10 together. Thanks Apple..